# inkscape: creating objects for subtitles file

Tags: inkscape

So I was using assdraw to create objects to overlay as subtitles in a subfile. The process is you create the vectors and then you copy the displayed equation and paste it into a sub program like aegisubs.

I was wondering If I could do the same process using inkscape instead of assdraw? Is there a way to access/copy the equation of an object I make so I can copy that into aegisubs?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If by *equation* you mean the SVG expression for an object, you can use the [object to/from string extension](https://inkscape.org/~jabiertxof/%E2%98%85object-to-and-from-string).

It allows to convert senected objects to string, and SVG strings back into objects.

You can also get the SVG expression using the XML editor in Inkscape (the `<>` icon).